# Is there an equivalent to yaml.safe_load in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, security, yaml

A rather [high-profile security vulnerability in Rails](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5028270) recently illuminated the potential dangers of parsing user-supplied YAML in a Ruby application.

A quick Google search reveals that [Python's YAML library](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) includes a `safe_load` method which will only deserialize "simple Python objects like integers or lists" and not objects of any arbitrary type.

Does Ruby have an equivalent? Is there any way to safely accept YAML input in a Ruby application without hand-writing a custom parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the lower level interfaces to `Psych` (the actual parser engine), it is possible to gain access to the lower level structures without serializing them back to Ruby objects (see http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/psych/Psych/Parser). This isn't as easy as `safe_load`, but it does provide a route to do it.

There may be other options that work in `Syck` and `Psych`, and that are more direct such as `safe_load`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! You can see I did as you suggested and [put it on GitHub](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml).

Answer (score 6):

Following [Jim's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348691/105570) I went ahead and wrote [**safe_yaml**](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml), a gem which adds the `YAML.safe_load` method and uses Psych internally to do the heavy lifting.